# Find largest element in a generic array method, Integer, String, Character

Tags: java, arrays, generics, conditional-operator

I have a method I have made that works well to find the smallest element in a generic array. However, when I try the same method but slightly different, every time I run it it returns 0. I have no idea why.

I would like the method that solves this issue to look as close to this method below. I do not want to import Generic.max or use collections, I want to do it in a more primitive way like below.

How can I use a method similar to this one below to find the max? When I try to change < 0 to > 0 it doesn't work. How could I make this min method become a max method?

```java
    public static <E extends Comparable<E> > int getSmallesElement(E[] list) {
        int minIndex = 0;
        // Iterate from i+1 ti i-1
        for (int index = minIndex + 1; index <= list.length - 1; index++) {
            minIndex = (list[index].compareTo(list[minIndex]) < 0 )? index : minIndex;
        }// end for 

        return minIndex;
    }// end getSmallest method
```

Like I said if I could use a conditional like my first method that would be great. I'm new to generics and I'm trying to get these methods to work for an Integer, String, and Character array.

Thank you.

Comment: `maxIndex = maxIndex;`...

Comment: What's Generic.max?

Comment: What will be according to your code the min/max index of an array with only one element? And of an array without any elements?

Answer (score 0):

You rewrote your conditional expression as an `if` statement, but you did not do it correctly: you want `maxIndex = index` instead of `index = maxIndex`.

Rather than assigning `maxIndex` on each iteration in both branches of the `if`, you could assign it only in the "true" branch, and drop the "false" branch altogether:

```
for(int index = maxIndex + 1; index <= list.length -1; index++) {
    if (list[maxIndex].compareTo(list[index] ) < 0) {
        maxIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the `index` as the loop goes instead of just setting the `maxIndex`:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E> > int getLargestElement(E[] list) {
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for(int index = 1; index <= list.length -1; index++) {
        if (list[index].compareTo(list[maxIndex] ) > 0) {
            maxIndex = index;
        }
    }
    return maxIndex;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why, but I am still returning 0

Comment: This snippet should work. Please share the input that you observe returns `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that finally worked.

```java
public static <E extends Comparable<E> > E getLargestElement(E[] list) {
        E max = list[0]; // set first value in array as current max
        for(int i = 1; i < list.length; i++) {
            if(list[i].compareTo(max) > 0 ) {
                max = list[i];
            }
        }// end for
        return max;
    }
```

Could someone explain to me why the other answers and the method I was trying to use kept returning 0? It looked sound to me, and so did all of your answers, but they didn't work.